# Can we post <apex:form> to an external website, so that another web page can consume this apex:form?

Tags: apex, visualforce, form

There are 2 web pages, one is salesforce visualforce page, and another one is some other web page hosted on a website. Both need to interact in such a way that : Form details from salesforce visualforce page will be passed to the external website such that there is direct redirection to that page and it has all the info passed by the visualforce page.

Is there any concept of passing the entire apex:form having inputHidden data to an external website(not a consuming api endpoint)?

Can we actually post apex:form to external websites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apex:form` is wired up to call Visualforce controller methods. It cannot directly be used to submit data to a third party resource. You can, however, have your `apex:commandButton`, `apex:commandLink`, or `apex:actionFunction` return a `PageReference`, which will cause a redirect to the third-party site. However, those parameters will be passed to the site in the URL, not as a POST. You could render a hidden `<form>` on the page and submit it by submitting it via JavaScript after your controller action finishes executing, but that would be a separate step.

Example:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!doSomething}" reRender="hiddenform" oncomplete="submitForm()" label="Save" />
<script>
function submitForm() {
  document.querySelector('#submitForm').submit();
}
</script>
<apex:outputText id="hiddenform">
  <form action="https://myothersite.com/path" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="value1" value="{!HTMLENCODE(value1)}" />
  </form>
</apex:outputText>
```

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox